# Error compiling a simple class that uses a single dependency jar file

Tags: java

I have a simple class (RJson.java) that imports org.json.JSONObject from json jar file.

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
public class RJson{
  public static void main(){
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
  }}
```

and also I have downloaded the JAR file from [here](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.json).

I can easily compile the RJson class using:

```
javac -cp json.jar RJson.java
```

and that creates **RJson.class**.
But during runtime when I run:

```
java -cp json.jar RJson
```

I recieve the following error:
*Error: Could not find or load main class RJson*.

Can someone please guide me how I can solve this problem?
Note: I don't want to use Ant or Maven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're running the code, your classpath *only* contains `json.jar` - not the current directory.

Run it as:

```
java -cp json.jar:. RJson
```

(or use a semi-colon instead of a colon if you're on Windows) and I suspect it'll be fine.